# Issue in making Remote powershell connection from windows 7

Tags: powershell-remoting

I am trying to make persistant remote powershell connection from Windows7(32-bit) to exchange Server 2013,such that I can run some powershell commands from My windows7
machine  as i am running it on server.
I am following steps from this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.150).aspx

I had already installed
.net Framework Version 4.5,
Windows Framework 4.0,
and windows already has SP1 installed.

Now, the issue is in running this command

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://ServerName.domain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
```

Everytime it results into an error that is

> New-PSSession : [ex13r.corp.local] Connecting to remote server ex13r.corp.local failed with the following error
> message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using
> Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
>  Possible causes are:
>   -The user name or password specified are invalid.
>   -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
>   -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
>   -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
>   -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
>  After checking for the above issues, try the following:
>   -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
>   -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or
> use HTTPS transport.
>  Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>    -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more
> information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
> At D:\path.ps1:1 char:10
> + $session=New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
>    gTransportException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticationFailed,PSSessionOpenFailed

*NOTE*
Client machine(Windows7) is not connected to any domain

1. I added the server to the list of trustedHosts
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy to remotesigned
3. Winrm service is also running.
4. Windows firewall is turned off on both the systems.

My Powershell Configuration after framework 4.0 installation is as follows

```
Name                           Value

----                           -----

PSVersion                      4.0

WSManStackVersion              3.0

SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18408

BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406

PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}

PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

My efforts are going in no direction,the error remains the same.Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure about the credentials? check if it is correct or not.

Comment: Yes,Credentials are absolutely correct.I tried for several times.I had successfully created remote powershell connection from windows 8.1.